# ASP.net reporting methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This is frustrating me to no end. I need to create a report based off a SQL query to be displayed in a report viewer on an asp page. Seems like it would be simple but I can't seem ti find an example of how to accomplish this. I don't need a stored procedure I need something I can add variables to like stringbuilder. The user will give an input and then the report will populate based off the query that the input was passed too. Simple seems like but anything dealing with a report seems to want the wizard. What can I do to get a report that looks good and I can use a sql query to bind data to? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your tags are confusing.  Are you using .net or SSRS?

Comment: I am using .net apology for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gridview to display table from a database. A good start can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Bind-GridView-to-DataTable.aspx). 
Please give us some additional info on what you need so that we can able to help more. :)

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is the user put in an id in textbox. then it pass that value to my query that then will build my report. then display thus report in report viewer. I got all but getting the value into the query for the report as the report needs dataset

Comment: Showing us your code would really help us to help you.